# How do i define generic parameter "on the fly"?

Tags: scala, generics

How do i define generic parameter "on the fly"?
Example:
I have some method `def get[T](name: String)`

Simple case class

```
case class User(name: String, password: String, age: Option[Int])
```

Then i get all my case accessors

```
def getMethods[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].decls.sorted.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
  }.toList

val caseAccessors = getMethods[User]
```

And i need to call `get` method with every accessor method and parametrize it by accessorMethod return type

For example:

```
caseAccessors.map{accessorMehtod => get[accessorMehtod.returnType](accessorMehtod.name)}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you're invoking a method using runtime reflection then you don't need to provide a generic type - generics are erased at runtime.

Comment: Generics are a purely compile time construct, they provide type safety. What you are doing is inherently unsafe and requires explicit casting. Generics are of no use.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in the comments to your question - it's not possible to extract type from runtime-reflection of object in compile-time - so you're loosing all typechecks (and possible have to do `asInstanceOf` somewhere).

But, *depending on your needs* - you could choose some typesafe alternative, like using [Shapeless Records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records), which could also allow you to access fields by name, but in typesafe way. So, there will be just `HList[String :: String :: Option[Int]]` (which stores all field types inside) instead of `List[Method]`.

You can also easely convert record into the case class: `User(userRecord("name"), userRecord("passsword"),userRecord("age")`. But it's all requires that possible field names ("name", "password", etc.) should be known at compile time.